# Change background-color of a row in list view with FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to make change the color of each event rows in the listMonth view with FullCalendar to a specific color depending of what is entered in "event.status".

Here's my FullCalendar code:

```
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'listMonth, month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          defaultView: 'listMonth',
          locale: 'fr',
          contentHeight: 600,
          navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
          selectable: false,
          eventRender: function(event, element, view) { 
            element.find('.fc-widget-header').append("<div style='color:#fff'>Conférencier choisi</div>");
            element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.lieu); 
            element.find('.fc-list-item-title').append("<br/>" + event.lieu); 
            element.find('.fc-list-item-title').append("<a href='" + event.lienconferencier + "'><div class='conferencier-calendrier-container'><div style='float:left;background-image:url(" + event.photoconferencier + ");width:40px;height:40px;background-size:cover;border-radius:100px;'></div><div style='float:left;padding-left:5px;font-weight:normal;'><strong>Conférencier</strong><br>" + event.conferencier + "</div></a>"); 

if (event.status == "Annulé") {
                    element.css('background-color', '#000');
                }

          },
          selectHelper: true,
          editable: false,
          eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
          events: [
            {
              title: 'Example',
              start: '2018-05-05',
              end: '2018-05-06',
              color: '#ff0000',
              lieu: 'Montreal',
              numero: '300445',
              status: 'Complet',
              conferencier: 'John Doe',
              photoconferencier: 'http://www.example.com/img/profile.jpg',
              lienconferencier: 'http://www.example.com/profile/link.html',
              url: 'http://www.google.com'
            },
    {
              title: 'Example2',
              start: '2018-05-08',
              end: '2018-05-010',
              color: '#ff0000',
              lieu: 'New York',
              numero: '300446',
              status: 'Annulé',
              conferencier: 'Steve Jobs',
              photoconferencier: 'http://www.example.com/img/profile2.jpg',
              lienconferencier: 'http://www.example.com/profile/link2.html',
              url: 'http://www.apple.com'
            },
          ],
        });
```

As you can see, the part where the condition is set is:

```
if (event.status == "Annulé") {
                    element.css('background-color', '#000');
                }
```

But it's not working. Nothing happens at all.

I also tried:

```
if (event.status == 'Annulé') {
            $(".fc-list-item").addClass('test');  
          } else {
            $(".fc-list-item").removeClass('test');
          }
```

But not working either.

Any idea what I must change in my code to make this work?
Thanks a lot!

---

EDIT :

The data in events up here is fake data. The real data is being generated by a CMS. So perhaps it's testing the condition before the data is added to the calendar. I tried this:

```
window.onload = function () {
          if (event.status == "Annulé") {
                    element.css('background-color', '#000');
                }
}
```

But it's not working. Any idea what I need to do?
Thanks!

---

EDIT 2 :

Turns out there was a line of code missing in this post code, that is in my file code. Here is the missing line:

```
return ['all', event.conferencier].indexOf($('#filter-conferencier').val()) >= 0 && ['', event.numero].indexOf($('#numero').val()) >= 0;
```

So the eventRender code looks like this:

```
  eventRender: function(event, element) { 
    element.find('.fc-widget-header').append("<div style='color:#fff'>Conférencier choisi</div>");
    element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.lieu); 
    element.find('.fc-list-item-title').append("<br/>" + event.lieu); 
    element.find('.fc-list-item-title').append("<a href='" + event.lienconferencier + "'><div class='conferencier-calendrier-container'><div style='float:left;background-image:url(" + event.photoconferencier + ");width:40px;height:40px;background-size:cover;border-radius:100px;'></div><div style='float:left;padding-left:5px;font-weight:normal;'><strong>Conférencier</strong><br>" + event.conferencier + "</div></a>"); 
      return ['all', event.conferencier].indexOf($('#filter-conferencier').val()) >= 0 && ['', event.numero].indexOf($('#numero').val()) >= 0;


      if (event.status == "Annulé") {
                console.log('Sa fonctionne');
                element.css('background-color', '#000');
            }
  },
```

If I remove that "return ['all'..." part of the code, it works fine. Any idea where the conflict is?

Comment: Did you verify that `event.status` is actually returning `Annulé`?

Comment: it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/574/ with the sample data given. I can only assume, as Kramb said, that your actual source data is not what you think it is. You can easily check either in your page source, or, if you fetch the data via ajax, then in your network tab. Also I don't know if your data and page is properly encoded for UTF8, that could play a part.

Comment: I see. I think the issue is that I am using a CMS to populate the events. So perhaps the condition is being checked before the CMS populates the data, so it returns false to the condition. What should I do? I thought of adding "window.onload" function but it's not working either. I edited my main post. Thanks guys

Comment: Even if it's not exactly the behaviour you ask for, you can also use the `backgroundColor` option in each 'Annulé' event that will set the color of the event dot as in this example https://jsfiddle.net/hj3xmj4b/

Comment: Thanks Laura, but I don't want to change the dot color, as it's already set using the "color" option. I'm really talking about the whole row color. Thanks though

Comment: "perhaps the condition is being checked before the CMS populates the data" .... no because "eventRender" only runs when there is an event object to draw, so what you're saying is impossible. Think about it - you have access to the `event` object right there in that callback, so it must exist. Instead of speculating, actually check your output as I suggested. How is the data being populated? Static array injected into the JS? or `events` specified as a JSON feed URL? Or custom feed?

Comment: Makes sense. I have checked the source code, and it shows "Annulé" in certain events "status" option. I also made a function so that when I hover an event, it shows the "event.status" in the console, and it shows "Annulé" when I hover events with "Annulé" as the status. I'm really lost here.

Comment: maybe it's not techincally the same UTF character or something, or it's from a different encoding, despite appearing to be similar. I agree it's a bit puzzling. Are you sure it's that test which is definitely the problem? Get it to log something when it enters the `if` block, e.g. `if (event.status == "Annulé") {
  console.log("found the status");
                    element.css('background-color', '#000');
                }` just in case somehow it's the CSS setting which is failing

Comment: Oh! It's working now. I found the issue. In the example up here, I haven't included the latest part of the code I have added to add filters to find specific events. I delete that line of code and it's working now. So there's a conflict there. I changed the order of the code, checking the status condition before returning the filters, and it's working fine now. Thanks a ton for helping me figuring this out guys!

Answer (score 0):

There was a line of code missing in my main post, in the eventRender section of the code.

That line :

```
return ['all', event.conferencier].indexOf($('#filter-conferencier').val()) >= 0 && ['', event.numero].indexOf($('#numero').val()) >= 0;
```

was being called before the condition check with "event.status", and that was causing the issue. I changed the order of the lines to check the condition before returning the filters, and it's working now. Code went from:

```
  return ['all', event.conferencier].indexOf($('#filter-conferencier').val()) >= 0 && ['', event.numero].indexOf($('#numero').val()) >= 0;


  if (event.status == "Annulé") {
            console.log('Sa fonctionne');
            element.css('background-color', '#000');
        }
```

To

```
if (event.status == "Annulé") {
                    console.log('Sa fonctionne');
                    element.css('background-color', '#000');
                }
          return ['all', event.conferencier].indexOf($('#filter-conferencier').val()) >= 0 && ['', event.numero].indexOf($('#numero').val()) >= 0;
```

It did the trick. Thanks for your help. Especially ADyson.

Comment: Yes...code after a return statement is never executed, because the return statement ends the execution of the function

Comment: Thanks a lot @ADyson for helping me and taking the time to explain these things.